# How do I set kAbPersonKindOrganization using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, jqtouch, cordova

Anyone know how I can set a new contact as a kABPersonKindOrganization in iphone using jQtouch + PhoneGap)

I am able to set the new contact as a normal contact but not as a organization.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it cannot be done, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/blob/master/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Contacts.m)